# Include statement is not showing for joining table in console application intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have MVC project in which I am using Entity framework. I am using database first approach here. I need to create console application for scheduling task so I created console application inside existing solution and I gave reference to my models. I am able to access my database in console appreciation.Now I need to join two different table from database. Like this :

```
var context = geton.schedule_month.Include("History").Include("market").Where(o => o.ID == 0 && o.app_cost != 0);
```

But when I try to type above code in console application I am not able to see Include statement. In fact I have reference to linq also. So what mistake I am doing here?

**Update** : I referred to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and add `using System.Data.Entity;`. Even it is not showing in my console application.

Comment: Have you use this line: using System.Linq; ?

Comment: @jannagy02 Yes i have that using statement.

Comment: this name is a little confusing: var context = ...
your context instance is the geton? Right?

Comment: @jannagy02  yes geton is instance and schedule_month is table name. And I am trying to include History table and Market table to that instance.